# Video analysis on 20.04

Tags: display-resolution, 20.04

i have a laptop ACER with 14' display FHD. I installed 20.04 Ubuntu and my video analysis 1920x1080 have very small words. What resolution is the best for my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `xrandr` will show the available resolutions and the current one with an asterisk.

```
xrandr | fgrep '*'
```

Comment: Ok but i dont want to see  my resolution only. I ask what resolution is the best for my laptop  because the words is too small with current resolution